# EXC_BAD_ACCESS Error When Using Lambda Callback in C++ SocketIO Client

Tags: c++, pointers, lambda, socket.io, reference

I am developing a class in C++ that involves handling SocketIO events. The class contains a method that binds an event to a function using a lambda. This lambda captures `this` in the constructor of the class. However, I'm encountering an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error when the callback is executed. The problem seems to be specifically related to the capturing of `this`.

I have a class `Queue` where I'm registering callbacks for SocketIO events. I'm using a lambda to handle these events, and within this lambda, I'm capturing `this`. The error seems to occur when the callback is invoked. The constructor of the class today is actually like this:

```cpp
Queue::Queue(const std::string &node_name, std::unique_ptr<ClientStreamer> sio_client) : rclcpp::Node(node_name), node_name_(node_name), robot_status_(RobotStatus::NOT_INITIALIZED),
                                                                                         sio_client(std::move(sio_client)) {
    this->queue_ = std::vector<geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped>();

    this->timer_ = this->create_wall_timer(std::chrono::milliseconds(300), std::bind(&Queue::timer_callback_, this));

    // Subs
    enqueue_subscription_ = this->create_subscription<geometry_msgs::msg::Pose>(
            "enqueue", 10, std::bind(&Queue::enqueue_callback_, this, std::placeholders::_1));
    status_subscription_ = this->create_subscription<std_msgs::msg::String>(
            "status", 10, std::bind(&Queue::status_callback_, this, std::placeholders::_1));

    // Pubs
    dequeue_publisher_ = this->create_publisher<geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped>("dequeue", 10);
    log_publisher_ = this->create_publisher<vallet_msgs::msg::Log>("log", 10);

    // SIO Events Listeners
    this->sio_client->client->socket()->on(
            "/enqueue",
            sio::socket::event_listener_aux([&](std::string const &name,
                                                sio::message::ptr const &data,
                                                bool isAck,
                                                sio::message::list &ack_resp) {
                this->on_sio_enqueue_(data);
            }));
}
```

And the function that I calling inside the lambda function is like this:

```cpp
void Queue::on_sio_enqueue_(const std::shared_ptr<sio::message> &data) {
    try {
        json parsedData = json::parse(data->get_string());
        
        auto x = parsedData.at("x").get<float>();
        auto y = parsedData.at("y").get<float>();

        RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Received pose: (%f, %f)", x, y);

        geometry_msgs::msg::Pose::SharedPtr pose = std::make_shared<geometry_msgs::msg::Pose>();

        pose->position.x = x;
        pose->position.y = y;

        this->enqueue_callback_(pose);

    } catch (const std::exception &e) {
        RCLCPP_ERROR(this->get_logger(), "Error in callback: %s", e.what());

        auto info = this->generate_log_("ERROR: " + std::string(e.what()));

        this->log_publisher_->publish(info);
    }
}
```

And the header file from the ClientStreamer class looks like this:

```cpp
using json = nlohmann::json;

// TODO: Remove the Node inheritance
class ClientStreamer : public rclcpp::Node {
public:
    typedef std::function<void(const json&)> callback_json;

    explicit ClientStreamer();
    ~ClientStreamer() override;

    void on_JSON(const std::string &event, const callback_json &callback);
    std::unique_ptr<sio::client> client;

private:

    std::mutex _lock;
    std::condition_variable_any _cond;
    bool _connect_finish;

    void on_connected_();
    void on_close_(sio::client::close_reason const &reason);
    void on_fail_();
    void emit_(const std::string &topic, const std::string &message);
    void on_message_(const std::string &name, sio::message::ptr const &data, bool isAck, sio::message::list &ack_resp);
};
```

But as you can see, this approach utilizes a property, `client`, that I intend to make private. Therefore, I have created a method named `on_JSON`. This method not only simplifies the process of binding events to callback functions but also enables me to turn `client` into a private property.

Here's a simplified version of my class the `on_JSON` method:

```cpp
void ClientStreamer::on_JSON(const std::string &event, callback_json const &callback) {
    this->_client->socket()->on(event, sio::socket::event_listener_aux(
        [&](std::string const &name, sio::message::ptr const &data, bool isAck, sio::message::list &ack_resp) {
            // Handling the event and invoking the callback passing in the correct form a JSON
            // *Just an example*
            callback(json::parse(data->get_string());
        }));
}
```

And here is how I tried to refact my constructor:

```cpp
Queue::Queue(const std::string &node_name, std::unique_ptr<ClientStreamer> sio_client) : rclcpp::Node(node_name), node_name_(node_name), robot_status_(RobotStatus::NOT_INITIALIZED),
     
    // previous code

    // SIO Events Listeners
    this->sio_client->on_JSON(
            "/enqueue",
            [&](const json& data) {
                // handling data
            });
}
```

The problem arises when the callback function (passed to on_JSON) is invoked. It seems to cause an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. The lambda function captures this pointer, and I suspect the issue is related to how this is being captured and used within the lambda function.

In the original code that I presented earlier, the constructor is currently functioning correctly. However, with my simplified approach, an issue arises: when it reaches the point of executing the callback, an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error occurs. Interestingly, it doesn't even enter the callback function, also known as the lambda function.

The first thing that I have ensured that the lifecycle of the involved objects is properly managed. sio_client_ is a std::unique_ptr within the class, so it should be alive as long as the class instance exists.

Further more, I removed the context which the lambda function is getting, and the code just works fine (In my case I cannot remove `&` as my callback depends on the `this`). I could access the data, print stuff, worked just fine.

Furthermore, I removed the context that the lambda function was accessing, and the code then worked fine. After making this adjustment, I was able to access the data and print stuff without any issues (I cannot remove the `&` because my callback depends on `this`, this was just a test to see if `&` is actually the problem).

So my questions are:

1. Could the manner in which this is captured in the lambda function be causing the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error?
2. Is there something specific in the way on_JSON handles the lambda function that could lead to this issue?
3. How does the approach that utilizes the client itself differ from the on_JSON approach?

Any insights, suggestions, or alternative approaches to debug or resolve this issue would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Capturing references to local variables is your issue.